# Mail attachment from form file field and send mail through sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq

In rails, I want to send email using Action Mailer with attachment that is obtained from form file field and want to delay it through sidekiq.

And I have written code as below.

In view:

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: 'my_controller', action: 'my_mail', method: 'post' }, { multipart: true }) do %>
    <%= form_field_tag(:attachment) %>
<% end %>
```

In controller:

```
def my_mail
    MyMailer.delay.my_mail(params)
end
```

In Mailer:

```
def my_mail(message)
    attachments['attachment'] = File.read(message[:attachment].tempfile)
    mail(from: ENV['MY_MAIL'], to: ENV['MAIL_RECIVER'], subject: 'this is subject')
end
```

But, IOError will be raised due to inaccessibility to the file.

And, I perform File read operation in controller as

```
def my_mail
   MyMailer.delay.my_mail(File.read(params[:attachment].tempfile))
end
```

Now, I can make attachment in Mailer as

```
attachments['attachment'] = message
```

And Now, It does work as i want but It's very bad to read file in controller due to security reason.

So, Now I want to know the best way to attach the file obtained from form and send it through sidekiq.

Answer (score 5):

**In controller:**
Its not good to send bulk objects like `params` and `File` object in `redis-server` via `sidekiq`. Lets make it simple

```
def my_mail
    # get absolute path of temporary location uploaded file
    attachment_tmp_path = File.absolute_path(params[:attachment].tempfile)
    MyMailer.delay.my_mail(attachment_tmp_path)
end
```

**In Mailer:**

```
def my_mail(attachment_tmp_path)
    attachments['attachment'] = File.read(attachment_tmp_path)
    mail(from: ENV['MY_MAIL'], to: ENV['MAIL_RECIVER'], subject: 'this is subject')
end
```

> **Why security issue is warned?**
>   It is not considered good to directly use `params` without using strong params to limit only permitted attributes.
>
> **Note**:
>   Tmp uploaded files may not be available always as you have used `sidekiq` for background processing file uploaded by `sidekiq-client` may not be available when `sidekiq-server (Background version)` tries to access that tmp file when `sidekiq-server` being busy processed this task after very long long time.

**Conditions your approach may not work**:

- When you goto to production and need to run multiple instance. Lets
  say you need a separate utility instance to run `sidekiq` and
  `redis`. Then your `sidekiq-server` cannot locate the `tmp` location
  of `application_master`.
- When you `sidekiq-server` is busy in
  processing or is down for some time and resumes after long long time

Comment: Host-specific queues become extremely useful when you are trying to pass a temp file between Rails and Sidekiq: http://www.mikeperham.com/2013/11/13/advanced-sidekiq-host-specific-queues/